# Replace the string that begins with a given characters

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I am trying to find a way to replace some special strings with their relative smileys.

for example replace \ue40a with `<img src="image/path"/>`
and replace \ue53c with `<img src="image/path/2"/>`

How can I find , in a given text , each string that begins with \ue and get the three next characters and then replace them by an img tag ?

Thank you for your help !

Comment: Is there any JavaScript you've written to try to solve this?

Comment: the regex is fairly simple but how do you know to map `40a` to `/path` and `53c` with `/path/2`?

Comment: Since we do not know which language or server architecture you use, my only recommendation are [regular expressions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) or simply the search and replace function of your favourite text editor. You need to supply more information to get a detailes answer.

Comment: @Rhumborl I have an array that contains each string key associated to a path value

Comment: Replace the string `\ue40a` (ie `x = "aa \\ue40a bb"` ) or the character `\ue40a` ?

Comment: @MatthiasHauert what more informations should I give ?

Comment: What if those characters are inside a html tag? Then you probably don't want to replace, so you must parse html in order to know whether you should replace or not. But [you can't parse html with regex](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1529630).

Comment: @MatthiasHauert The javascript,jquery tags are suggestive

Comment: @AlexK. replace \ue40a by an image html tag

Comment: If possible , can post `html` ? Thanks

Comment: @Rhumborl But it may still be a good idea to handle this on the server side...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use replace and a match function:

```
input = input.replace(/(\\u[a-f0-9]{4})/gi, function(m) {
    switch (m.toUpperCase())
    {
        case "\\UE40A": return '<img src="image/path"/>';
        case "\\UE53C": return '<img src="image/path/2"/>';
        default: return m;
    }
});
```

Comment: Try it with `input = '<div data-foo="\\UE40A"></div>'`.

Comment: If you alert() your *real* input string and actually *see* "\ue40a" then to replicate that string in javascript you need to use two \\ instead of one \ - http://jsfiddle.net/ztj0akp6/